# how to assign 20 interrupts as only 16 lines can be configured as EXTI lines?

Tags: interrupt, stm32

i'm using stm32f091xc controller where i want to configure 20 GPIO lines as EXTI lines with rising_falling edge.How can i configure these 20 lines, as only 16 gpio lines can be configured as EXTI lines?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. There are only 16 external interrupts<sup>1</sup>, and each one can only be mapped to one GPIO.

You will need to either:

- Poll for events on some or all of these GPIOs instead of using interrupts.
- Find a way to aggregate events on some of these GPIOs in external hardware, e.g. by ORing together certain inputs.
- Use an IO expander to handle some or all of these inputs.

---

1: Technically, there are another 16 EXTIs, but they're all used for internal events and won't help you here.

Answer (score 1):

You have to find 4 pins that can somehow be programmed to behave like EXTI sources. Some ideas:

- UARTS can generate an interrupt on CTS state changes.
- Timers can count state changes of their input lines. With an auto reload value of 1, they should generate an interrupt on every event.
- Comparator inputs